# How to set color transition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before anyone states this, yes, I know that you can transition things in css. But, I want to know how to transition background colors in javascript. I'm working on this function that changes the background of the div with the id of ex1 to a green color, but the setInterval function is only running once which is weird.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
div#ex1{color:white; background:black; width:300px; padding:0px 10px 10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
div#ex1:hover{cursor:pointer;}
div#ex1 h2{border-bottom:double 3px white; text-align:center; padding: 5px 0; margin: auto -10px;}
div#ex1 p{text-indent:5px;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="ex1">
  <h2>Transition Color</h2>
  <h4>Text:</h4>
  <p>Church-key seitan listicle locavore, mixtape biodiesel readymade crucifix health goth flexitarian direct trade mlkshk iPhone. Banjo tote bag readymade +1 skateboard deep v. Mixtape cred readymade gentrify. Banh mi keytar butcher, skateboard knausgaard </p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('ex1').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
 var tar = this;

var counter;

var backG = window.getComputedStyle(tar,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

console.log(backG);

 var re,gr,bl;
 gr = 0;
 bl = 0;

function chColor(tar)
{      gr =+31;
       bl=+10;
  if ( gr <153 && bl <51)
  { console.log('This is running');
    tar.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,'+gr+','+bl+')';
  } 
  else
  {
    clearInterval(counter);
    console.log(backG);
    console.log('The change has ended');   
  }
}

counter = setInterval(chColor(tar),100);

}, false);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your problem is? Is your problem that you can't figure out how to transition the colours? Or that you cannot make it run more than once? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

setInterval takes a reference to a function as the first argument which it will call at each interval. The way you have it, you are passing the return value from your function. Try this:

```
setInterval(function () {
     chColor(tar);
},100);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm curious as to what you mean as a return value. Because I don't have return keyword  in there. This  is the first time this happened to me when I tried to call the setInterval function, so I didn't know there were  certain thing that would only make it run once

Comment: Every function "returns". If you don't specify what gets returned it is undefined. In your case, YOU were calling your function (which is why it ran once) and then passing the "undefined" that it returned to setInterval. So what you were really saying in your code was "execute undefined every 100 milliseconds"

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines of code need to be corrected, as you'll want to use `+=` and not `=+`. Otherwise, the values will never increase.

```
gr += 31;
bl +=10;
```

Then see mcgraphix's post. You'll have to also do that, in order to get the animation to change colors when the text is moused over. (I was about to mention that too, but he beat me to it. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did that initially,  but the setInterval was only running once. So I thought maybe if I change the addition signs around it would do something.